# Ant as a dependency in a project that also uses ant for building/testing

Tags: java, testing, ant, build, classpath

In our Java project, we'd like to make use of a third-party jar that happens to have Apache Ant as one of its dependencies. However, we also use ant to build our project and run our test suite, and I'm concerned about the possibility of different versions of ant classes getting included on the classpath at runtime, especially during testing.

For example: suppose that the ant 1.8.4 jar gets pulled in as a dependency of our project, and some or all of its classes get packaged up with our classes into a master jar file for testing and eventual distribution. Now imagine that someone uses ant 1.7 to actually build this master jar file using our build.xml and initiate a test suite run on it -- could this cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine once you obey a few rules.

For example, the [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task has two important attributes you'll want to set:

- **includeAntRuntime**: Set this to *false* to exclude jars from the building ANT version
- **includeJavaRuntime**: Set to *false* to exclude jars from the JVM executing ANT
- **fork**: Set to *true* to run the task on a spawned VM

Other tasks like [junit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) have similar options (like fork) which should isolate their operation and limit them to the jars you define on their classpath.